# how to read vba code from hex stream extracted from vbaProject.bin?

Tags: excel, vba, com, hex, ole

I have a corrupted Excel `vbaproject.bin` extracted from `.xlam` add-in. How can I read modules with vba code extracted from this bin file as HEX streams? I'm using `oletools`, more details in this thread:

https://bitbucket.org/decalage/oletools/issues/38/extracted-vba-hex-files-from-vbaprojectbin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I never succeeded in recovering the VBA code with oletools. However I had some success with oledump:

http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/oledump-py/

I found it better suited to work with a corrupted workbook. So if you want to give it a try, download oledump.py:

https://github.com/DidierStevens/DidierStevensSuite/raw/master/oledump.py

You also need to install the module dependency "olefile" :

```
C:\temp>pip install olefile
```

Next, open your workbook with 7zip and extract the "xl\vbaProject.bin".
You can also extract each module present in "xl\vbaProject.bin\VBA\" if oledump is unable to read vbaProject.bin.

Then execute this command to display all the modules in the vbaProject.bin:

```
C:\temp>python oledump.py --vbadecompresscorrupt  C:\temp\vbaProject.bin
```

And to display the code from a module, add -s followed by the module number:

```
C:\temp>python oledump.py --vbadecompresscorrupt -s 3  C:\temp\vbaProject.bin
```

If reading the vbaProject.bin failed, extract the targeted module with 7zip and try to read it directly:

```
C:\temp>python oledump.py -r -v --vbadecompresscorrupt C:\temp\Module1
C:\temp>python oledump.py -r -v --vbadecompresscorrupt C:\temp\ThisWorkbook
```

Now, if at this point you haven't seen a line of VBA, then the code is most probably unrecoverable.

Comment: This worked perfectly! @florentbr thank you so much!

Comment: actually one of the modules did not extract, although notepad.exe shows some code between random characters.

Comment: The module is probably too corrupted to be decompressed and recovered. For more information: http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Formats/StreamCompression.php

Comment: I noticed option "-c" which allows to read parts of the stream, maybe it is still possible this way?

Comment: Probably not from what I've seen of the option. But the only way to be sure is to have a look at the code and try the different options on the corrupted module.